# List of official AndroidX library version

Tags: android, androidx

Where does one find official androidx library versions.

We are not allowed to use rc, example can't use androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0-rc01. Where do I find last official release version for androidx.arch.core:core-common?

I looked here - https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate they list release candidates , not the "released" version numbers.

Answer (score 3):

The current edition of [the AndroidX versions page](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/versions) contains a table showing each artifact group and the latest versions in various release stages. You would want to focus on the "Current Stable Release" column.

In general, the versions of the artifacts in the group share a common version, though that's not a guarantee. [The Google Maven repository page](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html) gives you the roster of every artifact and version.

So, using `androidx.arch.core:core-common` as an example:

- The versions page says that the current stable release for `arch` is 2.0.1
- The Maven repository page says that the highest version of `androidx.arch.core:core-common` without a `-rc01`-style suffix is 2.0.1

Comment: I missed that page - https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/versions thank you so much!

Comment: @SubodhNijsure: The table is fairly new -- I forget how old that overall page is.